# call my template operator<< only if no other found

Tags: c++, templates

I want to print state of my objects through toString member function, but I want to call it through `String::toString(var)`. But I want to do this only for object, who doesn't have `operator<<` defined.

My attempt is below.
I have template `operator<<` which call `toString`, but I hoped that this operator will be taken into account only if no other suitable `operator<<` has been found. I was obviously wrong :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct WithToString
{
    std::string toString()
    { return std::string ("foo") ; }
};

struct WithoutToString {};

struct String
{
    template <typename T>
    static std::string toString(T & var)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << var;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, T & var)
{
    s << var.toString();
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 5;
    std::cout << String::toString(i); //fine, prints 5

    WithToString w;
    std::cout << String::toString(w); //fine, prints foo

//    WithoutToString ws;
//    std::cout << String::toString(ws); //fine - give "toString is not a member" error

//    const char * s = "bar";
//    std::cout << String::toString(s); //error - operator << is ambiguous

//    std::string s = "bar";
//    std::cout << String::toString(s); //error - toString is not a member

    return 0;
}
```

How to achieve this behavior?

**EDIT**

here is my other attempt, but again fails with string and char *

```
template <class Type, class V>
class HasOperatorShiftLeft
{
    template <typename T, T> struct TypeCheck;

    typedef char Yes;
    typedef long No;

    template <typename T> struct ToString
    {
        typedef std::ostream & (T::*fptr)(V);
    };

    template <typename T> static Yes HasOpShift(TypeCheck< typename ToString<T>::fptr, &T::operator<< >*);
    template <typename T> static No  HasOpShift(...);

public:
    static bool const value = (sizeof(HasOpShift<Type>(0)) == sizeof(Yes));
};

template <typename T, int A>
struct toStringStr{};

template <typename T>
struct toStringStr<T,1>
{
    static std::string toString(T & var)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << var;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct toStringStr<T,0>
{
    static std::string toString(T & var)
    {
        return var.toString();
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::string toString(T & var)
{
    return toStringStr<T,HasOperatorShiftLeft<std::ostream,T>::value>::toString(var);
}
```

**EDIT**
my newest attempt is posted as Answer, because I think, it works

Comment: I'm afraid you will have define `operator<<` for each type and `template<typename T>` will be used as last resold.

Comment: What is your objective? What are you trying to do, in your real code?

Comment: @Nawaz I want to make my object printable through String::toString just with adding toString definition in my class... No frined operators<<.. But keep functionality through operators<< for datatypes which already supports it (int, std::string, class with overloaded op<<)

Comment: Do you like Java? Just kidding, but you are probably better off simply defining `operator<<` for the things that are missing it.

Comment: @relaxxx: It might be possible, but it'd be hard, and a bad idea.  Don't do this.

Comment: So, you want to break genericity of operator<< by devising your own silly member function, but at the same time preserve genericity of operator<<.

Comment: @relaxxx What against self-made (possibly friend) `operator<<`s? You don't like free functions because they're not part of the class's interface, right? And they shouldn't know anything about the class's internals either because they don't belong to the class, right? Wrong! A free function is nothing different from a public member function. And a free friend function isn't any more evil than a public member function that uses private data.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I will be fine with preserve operator<< for std::string, int, char* ...

Comment: @ChristianRau I know :) but I simply do not like overloading operator<< ... It is ugly and I do not like free functions... Silly I know

Comment: I have just edited my question with another try, please, take a look

Comment: @relaxxx: *Extremely* silly is you want to program in C++. Free functions are very widely used here, and `operator<<` for streams is a great example of how easily you can make something so extensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? 
I think it works just fine...

```
struct String
{
    template <typename T>
    static std::string toString(const T & var)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << var;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template<typename Elem, typename Traits, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<Elem, Traits> & operator <<(std::basic_ostream<Elem, Traits> & s, const T & var)
{
    s << var.toString();
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty easy, albeit stupid to do as described in the comments. With C++11:

```
template<class T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& val)
    -> decltype(os << val.toString())
{
  return os << val.toString();
}
```

This function will only exist if what's inside `decltype(..)` is a valid expression. Now just stream everything into an `std::ostream&` and call it a day. If a type has both `toString` and and overloaded `operator<<` for `std::ostream&`, well, tough. You'll get an "ambiguous call to overloaded `operator<<`" error.

---

For C++03, there's another option. Since you seem to *kinda* dislike free functions, I'll assume you like interfaces. As such, get yourself a `Streamable` base class with a `virtual std::string toString() const = 0` method and overload `operator<<` only for that. Presto, you have `operator<<` for all classes that implement that interface!

```
struct Streamable{
  virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Streamable const& s){
  return os << s.toString();
}
```

Or you can even go down to the meta level to get rid of the useless virtual function call:

```
template<class D>
struct Streamable{
  std::string toString() const{
    return static_cast<D const&>(*this).toString();
  }
};

template<class D>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Streamable<D> const& s){
  return os << s.toString();
}

// example:
struct Blub
  : public Streamable<Blub>
{
  // implement toString() ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you... Unfortunately I can't use C++11, but nice. About your C++03 version: If you take a moment, you will realize that I want to make object printable just with adding single one method. Derive from Streamable is not really nice solution... Please, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @relaxxx But just adding the same method to unrelated classes, instead of implementing a common interface is not very *object-oriented*, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but have you seen my answer? I think I do not need derived something... It is always good to eliminate multiple inheritance don't you think?

Comment: @relaxxx: Why, just because Java doesn't allow it? There's no harm from mixin classes like `Streamable`...